# R - How can I calculate mean with MICE using a loop and subsets?

Tags: r, casting, subset, mean, r-mice

I'm new to R and I use the package MICE for multiple imputation.
For basic analysis I want to calculate mean for different columns using subsets.
I have > 70 columns named `"Var_1"`, `"Var_2"` and so on.
The following statement works so far:

```
meanVal <- with(imp, exp = mean(subset(Var_1, Var_2 == 1)))
saveValue <- mean(unlist(meanVal$analyses))
```

At this point I want to use a function, because I have different conditions and a list of vars for which I want to calculate mean values.

```
doMean(imp, varlist, filter) {
    for (i in 1:length(varlist) {
        meanVal <- with(imp, exp = mean(subset(varlist[i], Var_2 == filter)))
        saveValue[i] <- mean(unlist(meanVal$analyses))
    }
}
#print(varlist[1]) is "Var_1"
#print(varlist[2]) is "Var_4"
#...
```

The expression `varlist[i]` is incorrect and I have no idea how to typecast it correctly.
The warning message is `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`.
I have tried `noquote()` and different `as.function_name()`-functions.

Edit: A small example

```
library(mice)
data("nhanes2")

head(nhanes2)

impZero <- mice(nhanes2, maxit = 0)
imp <- mice(nhanes2, maxit = 5, method = impZero$method, predictorMatrix = impZero$predictorMatrix, printFlag = FALSE)

rname <- c('chl', 'bmi')

#Working
MeanRes <- with(imp, exp = mean(subset(chl, bmi > 25)))
res <- mean(unlist(MeanRes$analyses)) #200.688888888
enter code here
#Not Working
MeanRes <- with(imp, exp = mean(subset(rname[1], bmi > 25)))
res <- mean(unlist(MeanRes$analyses)) #NA
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO, rNewbie!  You will be most likely to get your question answered if you follow the [helpful advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking questions and create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: The problem is that `rname` contains text/characters with your variable names but not the variables themselves. Replacing `rname[1]` with `get(rname[1])` should work. (I am  not sure, however, if this is considered good practice.)

Comment: @benimwolfspelz Thank you very much, my problem is solved. `rname` contains information from an external csv-file and they could change from time to time, so for me, it was the easiest way to get what I need without hundreds of if-clauses. :)
But for now everything works fine.